# How to build rgl with freeType on Windows

Tags: windows, r, freetype, rgl

I am trying (and ever so miserably failing) to build the `rgl` package with `freeType` on Windows, since, as it turns out, the `rgl` Windows binary I have installed via the Rgui doesn't include `freeType` support.

(The reason I need it is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284824/unicode-in-rgl-plot3d)!)

I'm not used to building things from source - so all the build instructions in the appropriate ReadMe files are basically indecipherable to me... I know this is a pathetic request but could someone please please give me a dummy's guide as to how to go about it?

I have the latest Windows version of R installed in C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2patched\bin

```
sessionInfo()<br>
R version 3.0.2 Patched (2013-10-08 r64038)<br>
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)<br>

locale:<br>
LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 <br>
LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   <br>
LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252<br>
LC_NUMERIC=C                           <br>
LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    <br>

attached base packages:<br>
stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    <br>
```

Thank you thank you thank you...